# Añadir un bucle para "correr" el mismo codigo en varias cryptos? (Python)

Tags: python, bucles, telegram

Llevo algunos meses aprendiendo Python y si bien soy un novato, normalmente luego de varias horas encuentro la manera correcta de desarrollar mi código.

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto Python para ser notificado via telegram cada vez que una criptomoneda supere cierto nivel de RSI (esa parte del codigo ya está lista), todo funciona bastante bien en una moneda específica, pero estoy buscando que el codigo se ejecute para todas las monedas del mercado y no hallo la forma de añadir el bucle para que el programa tome los nombres de las monedas desde un .txt y se ejecute al tiempo por cada una de ellas.

Adjunto código, cualquier aporte será de gran ayuda.

```
import websocket, json, pprint, talib, numpy, requests
from datetime import datetime


INTERVAL = '1m'
STREAM_NAME = 'ETHUSDT'
TIME_NOW = datetime.now()
SOCKET = (f'wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws/{STREAM_NAME.lower()}@kline_{INTERVAL}')
RSI_PERIOD = 14
RSI_OVERBOUGHT = 70
RSI_OVERSOLD = 30
closes = []

def telegram_bot_sendtext(bot_message):
    bot_token = 'token_here'
    bot_chatID = 'chat_id_here'
    send_text = 'https://api.telegram.org/bot' + bot_token + '/sendMessage?chat_id=' + bot_chatID + '&parse_mode=Markdown&text=' + bot_message
    response = requests.get(send_text)

    return response.json()
def on_open(ws):
    print(f'{TIME_NOW} - opened connection for {STREAM_NAME}')
    telegram_bot_sendtext(f'{STREAM_NAME} Connection opened at {TIME_NOW}')

def on_close(ws):
    print(f'{TIME_NOW} - closed connection for {STREAM_NAME}')
    telegram_bot_sendtext(f'{STREAM_NAME} Connection closed at {TIME_NOW}')

def on_message(ws, message):
    global closes
    print (f'{TIME_NOW} - received message')
    print (message)
    json_message = json.loads(message)
    pprint.pprint(json_message)

    candle = json_message ['k']
    is_candle_closed = candle ['x']
    close = candle ['c']

    if is_candle_closed:
        print(f'candle closed at{close}')
        closes.append(float(close))
        print ('closes')
        print (closes)
        

        if len(closes) > RSI_PERIOD:
            np_closes = numpy.array(closes)
            rsi = talib.RSI(np_closes, RSI_PERIOD)
            print('All rsis calculated so far ')
            print(rsi)
            last_rsi = rsi[-1]
            print(f'the current rsi is {last_rsi}')
            
            if last_rsi > RSI_OVERBOUGHT:
                print(f'{STREAM_NAME} RSI => 70 ')
                telegram_bot_sendtext(f'{STREAM_NAME} RSI IS OVERBOUGHT => {RSI_OVERBOUGHT} ')

            if last_rsi < RSI_OVERSOLD:
                print(f'{STREAM_NAME} RSI =< 30')
                telegram_bot_sendtext(f'{STREAM_NAME} RSI IS OVERSOLD =< {RSI_OVERSOLD} ')

ws = websocket.WebSocketApp(SOCKET, on_open = on_open, on_close = on_close, on_message = on_message)
ws.run_forever()
```

Comment: Puedes hacer una lista en tu código con el nombre de las monedas que quieres usar y crear un bucle sobre esa lista, por ejemplo `for i in STREAM_NAME:`. Pruébalo y nos cuentas.

Comment: Gracias, he estado intentando eso previamente, hacer una pequeña lista y empezar el codigo con el bucle 
STREAM_NAME = ['ethusdt', 'btcusdt', 'linkusdt', 'maticusdt']
for i in STREAM_NAME:

y se ejecuta en ethusdt pero como es una operacion infinita, nunca llega a ejecutarse por los demás nombres

Comment: Haz probado con usar threads?

Comment: Mejor que con _threads_, usa [asyncio](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/asyncio.html) con websockets. Cuando tenga tiempo, te podría poner algo de código.

Comment: Gracias por las respuestas, mi conocimiento de python aún no llega a threads o asyncio, empezaré a estudiar el tema. seria excelente si pueden añadir un ejemplo

Comment: No tengo conocimiento sobre bots de telegram, por lo que tal vez mi respuesta no sea muy correcta en tu caso

Comment: @Christian, el bot de telegram es bastante sencillo y solo está actuando como un "print", lo que se me ha dificultado es simplemente correr el codigo para todas las criptos al tiempo, de manera que se monitoreen individualmente.

Comment: Ok en un rato voy a ver si 0ublico una respuesta, ahora voy a desayunar:)

Comment: Hola, @davidjulian.es He estado mirando tu código y me doy cuenta que usas `websocket-client`, no `websockets`. Lamentablemente, `websocket-client` es [incompatible con `asyncio`](https://github.com/websocket-client/websocket-client/issues/496) y usar [`multithreads`](https://websocket-client.readthedocs.io/en/latest/threading.html) no está muy conseguido. Lo único que puedo recomendarte es que intentes usar [`websockets`](https://websockets.readthedocs.io) directamente.